# Laravel Broadcast using pusher. ToOthers not working

Tags: laravel, pusher

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
   headers:{
     'X-Socket-Id': Echo.socketId()
    }
  });
```

I also tried

```
var socket_id= Echo.socketId();
 var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
$.ajax({
                    /* the route pointing to the post function */
                    url: '/event',
                    headers: { 'X-Socket-Id': socket_id }
                    type: 'POST',
                    /* send the csrf-token and the input to the controller */
                    data: {
                        _token: CSRF_TOKEN,
                        message: 'a message'
                    },
                    //dataType: 'JSON',
                    /* remind that 'data' is the response of the AjaxController */
                    success: function (data) { 
                        $(".writeinfo").append(data.msg); 
                    }
                });
```

also laravel is supposed to add the x-socket-id header if im not mistaken without me doing it manually. according to this site

https://github.com/laravel/echo/blob/master/src/echo.ts
it contains this

```
registerjQueryAjaxSetup(): void {
        if (typeof jQuery.ajax != 'undefined') {
            jQuery.ajaxPrefilter((options, originalOptions, xhr) => {
                if (this.socketId()) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Socket-Id', this.socketId());
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Also in my broadcast i made sure i used ->toOThers()
it works fine on vue its, in blade where it does not want to work, it sends to everyone on the channel. I was thinking its because im using ajax i needed to add a header with socket ID but no im not so sure.

Comment: Found the problem. i have a layout with scripts. Then i have a blade file that has @extend layout. The layouts file has this     <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/test.js') }}"></script>. So it has both. When i delete the one with defer it works fine but all my vue components stop working. If i get rid of the one without defer all my other JavaScript on my blade disappear. How can i fix this

Comment: after doing more inspections to my files i saw that i had  this : require('./bootstrap'); on both of my files. When i removed one from my defer one it is working again. ToOthers is working as intended. I have tried sending messages back and forth and everyone is getting the data except the one who sends it. I tried removing ToOthers and everyone, including the sender gets the data.